ssh between two docker containers on different nodes
Hi I am trying to create (preferably passwordless) ssh connection between two docker containers (named master and worker_1) on mulitple nodes and having difficulties.
These are the options I tried so far:

Run containers with hosts network --network=host --uts=host --ipc=host

Add config, hostfile and known_hosts(was not being created automatically-dnt know why) files in .ssh directories of both containers with following contents respectively (here shown for master)
Host worker_1
 Hostname 192.168.0.29
 Port 22
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
 StrictHostKeyChecking no
 UserKnownHostsFile=/home/cuquantum/.ssh/hostfile



hostfile
worker_1 192.168.0.29

and known_hosts
worker_1, 192.168.0.29 ssh-rsa **public-key**

I edited following configurations in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, these are final lines in file
Port 22
HostKey /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no

In ssh_config, I changed
PasswordAuthentication no
StrictHostKeyChecking no
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Here is the ssh -vvv worker_1 at master node result after PasswordAuthentication no in ssh_config
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/cuquantum/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/cuquantum/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for worker_1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.29 is address
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.29 [192.168.0.29] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 0
debug1: identity file /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu3.2
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu3.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.29:22 as 'cuquantum'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/cuquantum/.ssh/hostfile:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.29
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:jGFeB1yRzu+GrXvAoJsDfkXmv5KadByUCE3THwfB4eY
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/cuquantum/.ssh/hostfile:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.0.29
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.0.29' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/cuquantum/.ssh/hostfile:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:zUkhBAQep2SAYToXhNrcmisMUDy5U1UXTg4dPo/zRMk explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zUkhBAQep2SAYToXhNrcmisMUDy5U1UXTg4dPo/zRMk
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa.pub RSA SHA256:zUkhBAQep2SAYToXhNrcmisMUDy5U1UXTg4dPo/zRMk explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zUkhBAQep2SAYToXhNrcmisMUDy5U1UXTg4dPo/zRMk
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
cuquantum@192.168.0.29: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Any help will be appreciated. Also my target basically is to run an a quantum circuit in distributed environment on these containers. Should I go for docker compose or swarm??

You should provide settings of both hosts and users individually and easier to follow. It's difficult to follow them now and some things look strange to me: IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, HostKey /home/cuquantum/.ssh/id_rsa
